# React lazy ругается на преобразование объекта в примитив

Tags: reactjs

решил использовать в своем проекте React lazy/динамические импорты и столкнулся с проблемой, в независимости от того какой это компонент(Просто верстка или отрисовка ответа с сервера) я получаю ошибку, для примера:

```
const Calculator = React.lazy(()=>import('../Calculator/Calculator'))

<React.Suspense fallback={<div>123</div>}> <Calculator /></React.Suspense>
```

ошибка ругается на преобразование объекта в примитив:

```
Unexpected Application Error!
Cannot convert object to primitive value
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
```

Comment: А этот самый `../Calculator/Calculator` что хоть экспортирует?

Comment: Да,вообще я уже разобрался,дело в самом экспорте он был именнованым ,оказалось нужен был export default,невнимательность(